# How to create a VSFTPD user with access to general folder

Tags: vsftpd

I have VSFTPD server (PAM+.db). Each user have access to their own folder (home/vftp/$USER). I want to create vsftpd user with access to specific folder (home/vftp) to see all subfolders($USER). How can I do this? Please, HELP!!!

Comment: Hello. What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: I use Ubuntu 18.04